# Blank phpmyadmin and localhost page in WAMP, how to connect port 80

Tags: wamp

I'm trying to download wordpress and so I downloaded WAMP, It's the WAMP SERVER (32 bit PHP 5.5) 2.5

I've seen a lot of help with this but my issue is, when I test port 80 it says it's not being used. I deleted skype because before it was using that. I have windows 10 and have no clue how to connect the ports. I also tried changing Listen to 8080 instead of 80 in the httpd.conf file but nothing changed so I put it back as 80. If anyone could tell me what's wrong I'd love to try it.

Comment: What do you mean by “Blank”?

Comment: Check if usbwebser work. This is alternative way. Do you install all libaries which requires wamp?

Comment: FUSION3K - "blank" as in the pages localhost and phpMyAdmin show up as blank pages when I click them through wamp.

ABDULLA - changing it to 85 didn't do anything either 

NORMIS - I'd like to think I installed all the libraries wamp requires

Comment: Blank pages are different from an error page saying the server did not respond, a blank page sounds like Apache is listening. You wrote that you tested port 80, how did you do that exactly?

Comment: Also, since you get a blank page, check the webserver error log for hints about a problem and try another page for testing purposes (for instance, a static HTML file in your web root).